# Obtain a Span<byte> over a struct without making a copy of the struct

Tags: c#, system.io.pipelines

I have been experimenting with `Span<T>` as part of `ReadOnlySequence<T>` and System.IO.Pipelines.

I am currently trying to obtain a `Span<T>` over a `struct` without using `unsafe` code and without making a copy of that `struct`.

My struct is simply:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public struct Packet
    {
        public byte TestByte;
    }
```

Method 1 - which works - but feels "unsafe"

```
    //
    // Method 1 - uses Unsafe to get a span over the struct
    //
    var packet = new Packet();
    unsafe
    {
        var packetSpan = new Span<byte>(&packet, Marshal.SizeOf(packet));

        packetSpan[0] = 0xFF; // Set the test byte
        Debug.Assert(packet.TestByte == 0xFF, "Error, packetSpan did not update packet.");
            // ^^^ Succeeds
        packet.TestByte = 0xEE;
        Debug.Assert(packetSpan[0] == 0xEE, "Error, packet did not update packetSpan.");
            // ^^^ Succeeds
    }
```

Method 2 - which doesn't work as intended as it requires a copy

```
    //
    // Method 2
    //
    // This doesn't work as intended because the original packet is actually
    // coppied to packet2Array because it's a value type
    //
    // Coppies the packet to an Array of Packets
    // Gets a Span<Packet> of the Array of Packets
    // Casts the Span<Packet> as a Span<byte>
    //
    var packet2 = new Packet();

    // create an array and store a copy of packet2 in it
    Packet[] packet2Array = new Packet[1];
    packet2Array[0] = packet2;

    // Get a Span<Packet> of the packet2Array
    Span<Packet> packet2SpanPacket = MemoryExtensions.AsSpan<Packet>(packet2Array);

    // Cast the Span<Packet> as a Span<byte>
    Span<byte> packet2Span = MemoryMarshal.Cast<Packet, byte>(packet2SpanPacket);

    packet2Span[0] = 0xFF; // Set the test byte
    Debug.Assert(packet2.TestByte == 0xFF, "Error, packet2Span did not update packet2");
        // ^^^ fails because packet2 was coppied into the array, and thus packet2 has not changed.
    Debug.Assert(packet2Array[0].TestByte == 0xFF, "Error, packet2Span did not update packet2Array[i]");
        // ^^^ succeeds

    packet2.TestByte = 0xEE;
    Debug.Assert(packet2Span[0] == 0xEE, "Error, packet2 did not update in packet2Span");
        // ^^^ fails because packet2Span is covering packet2Array which has a copy of packet2 
    packet2Array[0].TestByte = 0xEE;
    Debug.Assert(packet2Span[0] == 0xEE, "Error, packet2 did not update in packet2Span");
        // ^^^ succeeds
```

Further research shows that

`Span<T>` can be implicitly cast from a `byte[]`, eg, I could do

```
Span<byte> packetSpan = new Packet().ToByteArray();
```

But any current implementation of ToByteArray() I have is still making a copy of the Packet struct.

I can't do some something like:

```
Span<byte> packetSpan = (byte[])packet;
    // ^^ Won't compile
```

Comment: I think you can write user defined conversion operator(s). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators

Comment: I'm pretty sure that there's no way to do that for a struct in general without `unsafe`, because if you acquire a `Span` over all bytes of a struct you can potentially alter any bit in that struct in any way - that's inherently unsafe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no way of acquiring a `Span<byte>` over an arbitrary struct without `unsafe`, since such a span would allow you to change any bit of the struct in any way, possibly violating the type's invariants - that's inherently an unsafe operation.

Okay, but what about `ReadOnlySpan<byte>`? Notice that you had to put the `StructLayoutAttribute` on your struct for your code to be sensible. That should be a hint. Imagine trying to write an even simpler method, one that returns a `byte[]` for any arbitrary `T where T : struct`. You have to find out the size of the `struct` first, don't you? Well, how do you find out the size of a `struct` in C#? You can either use the `sizeof` operator, which requires an `unsafe` context and needs the struct to be an [unmanaged type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/unmanaged-types); or you can [`Marshall.SizeOf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.sizeof?view=netframework-4.8#System_Runtime_InteropServices_Marshal_SizeOf__1) which is wonky and works only on structs with sequential or explicit byte layout. **There's no safe, general way**, thus you cannot do that.

The `Span<T>` and `ReadOnlySpan<T>` weren't designed with accessing struct bytes in mind, but rather with spanning fragments of arrays, which have a known size and are guaranteed to be sequential.

If you are confident that you know what you're doing, you can do that in an `unsafe` context - that's what it's for. But note that your solution with `unsafe` doesn't generalise to arbitrary structs, for the reasons noted above.

If you intend your struct to be used as a buffer for IO operations, you might want to look into [fixed size buffers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/unsafe-code-pointers/fixed-size-buffers). They also require an `unsafe` context, but you can encapsulate the unsafeness inside your struct and return a `Span<byte>` to that fixed buffer. Basically anything that tackles the byte structure of objects in memory requires `unsafe` in .NET, as memory management is the thing that this "safety" refers to.

Comment: Both of these are such perfect answers.  Thanks for putting the effort in I really appreciate that and the pointers to fixed size buffers.  I need to choose one as the answer although I would like to choose both.  So I am afraid this is a case of my RNG.

Answer (score 4):

As it turns out, it *is* possible to do this, and in fact has been possible for quite some time... since dotnet core 2.1, if the docs are to be believed!

The magic ingredient is [`MemoryMarshal.CreateSpan`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.memorymarshal.createspan?view=net-6.0), which "*Creates a new span over a portion of a regular managed object.*"

```cs
        var packet = new Packet() { TestByte = 123 };
        var span = MemoryMarshal.CreateSpan<Packet>(ref packet, 1);
        var bytes = MemoryMarshal.Cast<Packet, byte>(span);
        bytes[0] = 100;
        
        Console.WriteLine(packet.TestByte);
```

Outputs *100* as you'd hope.

You're prevented from doing anything too stupid here, because `MemoryMarshal.Cast` raises an `ArgumentException` if the to- or from-types contain any managed references. `MemoryMarshal.CreateSpan` comes with a bunch of caveats and offers you a new way to shoot yourself in the foot, but hey... it doesn't require `unsafe` so go wild!

> This method should be used with caution. It is dangerous because the `length` argument is not checked. Even though the `ref` is annotated as `scoped`, it will be stored into the returned span, and the lifetime of the returned span will not be validated for safety, even by span-aware languages.

([`scoped ref`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-11#ref-fields-and-ref-scoped-variables) is a dotnet 7/C# 11 feature, but the method is available in older versions of dotnet without that particular keyword)

The blurb does not mention pinning at all, and I don't believe you need to worry about it. The span is constructed around a managed reference to the underlying struct (the `ref packet` bit) which is *not* a dumb pointer. As such I'd expect relocations of the struct (eg. because the managed object it was a member of to was moved by the GC) would be handled transparently by the runtime.

---

Just to confirm, you can absolutely do stuff like this:

```cs
        var packet = new Packet() { TestByte = 123 };
        var span = MemoryMarshal.CreateSpan<Packet>(ref packet, 100);
        var bytes = MemoryMarshal.Cast<Packet, byte>(span);
        new Random().NextBytes(bytes);
```

and cause a crash. So whilst this isn't `unsafe` in the keyword sense, it is absolutely *not* safe.

Comment: The GC is not an issue if `CreateSpan` cannot be used with managed objects.

Comment: @Schmid the things you are creating a span from might be a member of a managed type, and as such its address in memory is subject to change when its owning instance is relocated by the GC. I think though that GC isn't an issue because the `ref packet` that the span is constructed with is a managed reference that will cope with GC relocations. I'll update my answer to suit.